# Is there any analytic results of 3 × 3 SVD (Singular-value decomposition)?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I want to know the singular values of $\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}\\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}\end{bmatrix}$ where $\forall i,j (0\leq A_{ij}\leq 1)$.

Is there any analytic results helpful to find the singular values of this kind of matrices?